# how much difference in performance of Flutter and Koltin apps?

Tags: flutter, kotlin

I'm new to Android app development and I'm curious about the performance differences between Kotlin and Flutter. What are the performance differences between Kotlin and Flutter for Android app development, particularly in terms of page load times and responsiveness? I've heard that both technologies can deliver fast and responsive apps, but I'm not sure how they compare in these areas. Can anyone provide information on the performance differences between Kotlin and Flutter for Android app development, and can you provide sources to back up this information?

I've heard that Kotlin is faster than Flutter because it's native, but I'm not sure how much of a difference there is in terms of performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparing the performance differences between Kotlin and Flutter can be difficult because they are fundamentally different technologies. Kotlin is a programming language that runs natively on the Java Virtual Machine (JVM), while Flutter is a mobile app development framework that uses Dart programming language and its own rendering engine to build cross-platform mobile apps.

In terms of page load times and responsiveness, both Kotlin and Flutter can deliver fast and responsive apps, but there are some differences to consider.

Kotlin apps can be compiled to native code using tools like Android NDK, which can result in faster startup times and smoother performance compared to apps that run on a virtual machine. Kotlin also provides excellent support for Android Studio and Android platform, allowing developers to leverage the full power of the Android platform.

On the other hand, Flutter apps use a different approach to rendering and graphics, relying on its own rendering engine to draw and manage UI elements. This approach can result in faster UI rendering times and better performance on older devices. Flutter also provides support for hot reloading, which can greatly speed up the development process and improve the responsiveness of the app.

Ultimately, the performance of your app will depend on a variety of factors, such as the complexity of your app, the hardware and software of the device, and how well your code is optimized. Both Kotlin and Flutter can be used to build high-performance Android apps, and the choice between the two depends on your specific needs and preferences.

Here are a few resources that may help you further understand the performance differences between Kotlin and Flutter for Android app development:

Google's Flutter vs Kotlin: Which is Better for Android App Development? (https://www.digitalmesh.com/blog/flutter-vs-kotlin-for-android-development/)
Flutter vs Kotlin: Which One to Choose for Your Next Android App? (https://www.cleveroad.com/blog/flutter-vs-kotlin-which-one-to-choose-for-your-next-android-app)
A Performance Comparison of Flutter vs. Kotlin (https://blog.codemagic.io/flutter-vs-kotlin-performance-comparison/)

Comment: The shared links are working, update them. Pl